# Use of Without loss of generality (WLOG)

Tags: optimization, terminology, proof-writing

I encountered following usage of WLOG
Consider problem of minimizing $E:= (y-x)^2 + \lambda |x|^\tau$ and $\tau \in (1,2)$ and optimizing variable is $x$, we can assume without loss of generality that $y \geq 0 $.

My question: Is usage of WLOG in above is correct, if so then How?

I have tried a lot and ask my friends, but unable to get satisfactory answer. Please help me

--Pooja

Comment: I'm guessing because of the symmetry in $x$. Let $y < 0$ and $y' = -y$, then $E = (-y'-x)^2 + \lambda|x|^{\tau} = (y'+x)^2 + \lambda|x|^{\tau}$. Define $x' = -x$, then $E = (y'-x')^2 + \lambda|-x'|^{\tau} = (y'-x')^2 + \lambda|x'|^{\tau}$. As long as $x$ ranges over a symmetric interval (I'm assuming all of $\mathbb{R}$), then there's no problem and you can assume $y \ge 0$ since if it isn't, there's a clear relationship between the $x$ that minimizes the first equation and the $x'$ that minimizes the second.

Answer (score 4):

If $y\leq 0$, then letting $\tilde{y}=-y$ and $\tilde{x}=-x$, we have
$$(y-x)^2+\lambda|x|^{\tau}=(\tilde{y}-\tilde{x})^2+\lambda|\tilde{x}|^{\tau}$$
because the square of a quantity is the same as the square of its negative. Therefore, for any $y\leq 0$, finding the value of $x$ minimizing
$$(y-x)^2+\lambda|x|^{\tau}$$
is an equivalent problem to the one of finding the value of $\tilde{x}$ minimizing
$$(\tilde{y}-\tilde{x})^2+\lambda|\tilde{x}|^{\tau}.$$
Thus, we may as well assume that $y\geq 0$.

Comment: I wonder is it possible to have sign of $y$ and optimization variable $x$ has opposite sign at minimum $E$ ?